# Как реализовать tooltip с динамическим компонентом на Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, события

Делаю таблицу с большим количеством ячеек. Попробовал использовать библиотеку https://akryum.github.io/v-tooltip/. Для того, чтобы реализовать тултип с динамическим компонентом внутри, приходилось оборачивать элемент, на который необходимо наводить курсор, в дополнительный компонент v-popover.

Т.е. моя реализация была такая:

```
<template>
    <v-popover
        ref="element"
        :delay="{ show: 100, hide: 0 }"
        :trigger="tooltipTrigger ? 'manual' : 'hover'"
        :open="isTooltipVisual"
        :disabled="!tooltipEnable"
        @hide="onHide"
    >
        <slot/>
        <template v-slot:popover> 
            <component
                :is="tooltipTemplate"
                :data="tooltipData"
                :style="tooltipStyle">
            </component>
        </template>
    </v-popover>
</template>
```

это был компонент тултипа с динамическим компонентом внутри, в который передается имя шаблона.

И ячейки внутри таблицы приходилось оборачивать в него

```
<div class="grid-row grid-row__employees"
     v-for="(employee, employeeKey) in rolesMap[roleId].employees" :key="employeeKey">
     <wfm-tooltip
           v-for="(plan, planKey) in planMap[employee.id]" :key="planKey+employee.id"
           :tooltipEnable="isErrorInput() && isEditable(plan) && isSelectedCell(plan)"
           :tooltipTemplate="'common'"
           :tooltipData="{ text: 'Обозначение ' + errorInputValue + ' не найдено.' }"
           :tooltipTrigger="'keyup'"  
           :tooltipRemoveTrigger="'keydown'">
          <wfm-plan-cell
                :styles="[
                     employees-cell ${plan.idEmployee}-${planKey},
                     {
                       'weekend': plan.isWeekend || plan.isHoliday,
                       'select': isSelectedCell(plan),
                       'vert': isSelectedCell(plan) && isVerticalOrientation(),
                       'hor': isSelectedCell(plan) && !isVerticalOrientation(),
                       not-editable': !isEditable(plan)
                     }]"
                     tabindex="1"
         ></wfm-plan-cell>  
   </wfm-tooltip>
</div>
```

Из-за того что ячеек может быть 3000+ сайт просто начинает виснуть ужасно.

Как это можно реализовать правильно, а то из-за такого подхода слушателей на странице овер 3000...?

Comment: Можно попробовать монтировать тултип с компонентом динамически по событию (чтобы был только один экземпляр), используя апи Vue. Еще, когда такое количество ячеек, хорошо бы применять пагинацию.

Comment: Чтобы монтировать тултип с компонентом динамически по событию не получится использовать данную библиотеку, потому что в ней обязательно нужно оборачивать элемент с которым будешь работать. 
То есть создать директику, которая будет через стор передавать флаг и стили для позиционирования тултипа ?

Comment: Хм, я сомневаюсь что это ограничение с оберткой нельзя обойти. Через стор - можно, но я бы просто держал эти переменные в компоненте таблицы. Вообще позиционирование может сработать, но я подразумевал именно монтирование... типа `this.tooltip = new Vue(Object.assign({}, YourComponent, { propsData: {...} }));` + по событию `this.tooltip.$mount(selector);` + при разрушении компонента таблицы `this.tooltip.$destroy();`. Вот обмен данными видимо придется тоже через события - т.к. получится экземпляр Vue внутри экземпляра Vue, и хз как будет Vuex работать в такой ситуации.

Comment: Просто если проблема в большом кол-ве компонентов тултипа и неудобно с `v-if`, то возможно держать один такой компонент, и по событию перемонтировать его в другой элемент (в этом заключается идея. Насколько она рациональнее, не знаю - только подсказываю возможность. Пагинация с v-if изначально выглядит более эффективным вариантом, вопрос только в удобстве использования v-if).